# Perl script that makes variables

Tags: arrays, perl, variables, grep

I'm running a script that extracts links from a webpage but the webpage outputs a different number of correct urls everytime something on the webpage changes, which happens very often for the purpose of this script. My 'constraint' is the $tco it makes sure that the urls onyl start with http://t.co

```
$tconike = (grep /$tco/, @links);
print "$tconike\n";
```

This determines the number of urls that satifsy my needs, this prints '2'.

```
my @found = (grep /$tco/, @links);
if (@found) {
    for my $url (@found) {
    print "$found[0]\n";
    print "$found[1]\n";
    }
}
```

This prints the accual urls in this case there is two. ex
http://t.co/5
http://t.co/r
Can I have the perl script recignize the number of urls starting with t.co and add more varaibles (the $found[0] and $found[1]) based on what $tconike (the number of useable urls) outputs?

I NEED TO ACCESS THE URLS LATER WHEN I USE WWW::Mechanize TO FILL OUT FORMS ON THE URLS.

Comment: Why do you need it? You can just `for my $url (@found) { print "$url\n" }`.

Comment: I need to use the urls with WWW::Mechanize so I need them as variables so I can access them and there are multible variables, so I need it to make more $found all least I think

Comment: They already are inside `@found`. You should maybe start by reading a beginner's tutorial for Perl. It looks like you're not really aware of what you are doing. Try http://www.perl-tutorial.org for some good references.

Comment: Is there a certain section you recommend me look at?

Answer (score 2):

As choroba said, you don't need to do that. You can just use `print "$url\n"` instead of each array element individually, because it will call the block of the loop for each element inside `@found`.

---

If you still want more variables based on the number of urls, you could do the following. But this is not code that you should use in production. In fact, **don't use it**. It works, but it's intended as a joke. :)

```
my $code;
my @found = (grep /$tco/, @links);
if (@found) {
  for (my $i=0; $i<= $#found; $i++) {
    $code .= q{print "$found[$i]\n"} . qq{\n};
  }
  eval $code for @found; # this is very evil
}
```